# After migration from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018 viewing a changeset doesn't show related workitem

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2017

I started a migration from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018.

Everything worked fine.

But now I have a problem showing the work item for a changeset. I do th following:

1. I open the Source Control Explorer
2. Is elect the history for an item
3. I get a list of change sets.
4. I select a changes set and choose "Changeset details"
5. It takes a long long time and the files that are connected with the changeset are listed.

Problem: In the top area of the window in VS-2017 I see the information **"Unable to get artifacts from tool."** No information about the related workitem is shown.

But selecting "Open in browser" from the Action drop down menu works. The browser window for this changes set shows all information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a very busy server. The new code search took a lot of power and my memory for the VM was to small defined.

This message "Unable to get artifacts from tool" seams to be the way to show that a timeout appeared. After disabling the code search and waiting for a normalization, every thing works fine.